# Rails 4: How to execute HTML tags in text area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, textarea

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<% msg_textarea = "text text<br /> text" %>
<%= text_area_tag "my_texta", msg_textarea %>
```

And this is what is in the textarea:

```
text text<br /> text2
```

but I want:

```
text text
text2
```

I've tried:

```
<%= text_area_tag "my_texta", msg_textarea.html_safe %>
<%= text_area_tag "my_texta", simple_format(msg_textarea) %>
<%= text_area_tag "my_texta", simple_format(h msg_textarea) %>
```

But none of these worked for me.
How to exectute HTML tags in textareas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `\n` rather than `<br />`:

```
<% msg_textarea = "text text\n text" %>
<%= text_area_tag "my_texta", msg_textarea %>
```

Or alternatively, if you must have the `<br />` in the original, something like:

```
<% msg_textarea = "text text<br /> text" %>
<%= text_area_tag "my_texta", msg_textarea.gsub('<br />', "\n") %>
```

Both will leave you with a space on the second line - but it's easy enough to replace that too if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, this is too specific though. Isn't there a more general way to do it (like `.html_safe` - it usually works, but not in the textarea)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any more specific way. `html_safe` and `raw` are about having html tags treated as html (ie, rendered by the browser), vs having them display as actual text (ie, directly visible to the user). They're not about changing the actual content of the string per se.

Answer (score 0):

If br is the only tag troules you, gsub would help.
    text = "text text
 text2"
    text =text.gsub! "
", "\n"